# qgrep: How do I include files without an extension?

Tags: linux, grep

How do I use [qgrep](https://github.com/zeux/qgrep) to search in files without extension? Please note that this question is not about classic grep, but qgrep.

I use qgrep to search recursively through my project (similar to grep -r) file with various extensions like *.cpp, *.java, etc.

But how do I configure it to look in files without an extension, like:
Jenkinsfile, Dockerfile, any bash script that does not use the .sh or .bash extension etc.

This is my configuration file (~/.qgrep/prj.cfg):

```
C/C++
include \.(cpp|cxx|cc|c|hpp|hxx|hh|h|inl)$
# Java, C#, VB.NET
include \.(java|cs|vb|jsf)$
# Perl, Python, Ruby
include \.(pl|py|pm|rb)$
```

Comment: Try using `ag` (aka the silver searcher) instead. It does search across all text files, and is fastest grep-like utility.

Comment: I do not use `qgrep` but its doc says that it uses regular expressions. A filename without extension is a file name that contains no dot, so I would try `^[^\.]*$` (unsure for the backslash...)

Comment: @Serge Ballesta: it uses regexps for the search matches inside the files, not for the file names themselves.

Comment: The linked page contains: *Project configuration file format..., and a set of include/exclude **regular expressions**,*, and later *Searching for project files `qgrep files <project-list> <search-options> <query>`
... you can select a search style using the following options

fp - search in file paths using a **regular expression** (unless l flag is used)
     This option is the default.*. I think you could have a try at it.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to just enumerate all files without an extension in the qgrep cfg file (cat ~/.qgrep/prj.cfg), like this:

```
include Dockerfile
include Jenkinsfile
...
```

Using a regexp to match all files without an extension is not a good idea, because it will also match all binary files without extensions, and you don't want to search through those also because it will decrease speed.

If you have text files without extension without a specific name, you can use a regexp but you need to make sure that it only matches those text files you are interested in, and not any binary file.